# no suitable method for maketext(ActivityName,String,int)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i have created the activity below for my first (actually for testing) application for Android. But it throws me an error i cannot find how to fix,so please could you help me a bit here?

```
package com.app.myapplication;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AboutMeActivity {
    public void showAboutMessage(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My name is Kostas!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

PS: consider this is my very first android application, though I have some experience with Java

Comment: Please note that the tags on the question already tell the people an idea of which technologies are used: Java, Android. No need to add them in question title.

Comment: Put "extends Activity" after AboutMeActivity and take it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass a `Context` to the `makeText` method. Here this is not a context. It is just a reference of your `AboutMeActivity` class which is not an activity

May be you are trying to create an `Activity`. if so then you have to extend `Activity` class like this

```
public class AboutMeActivity extends Activity
```

Activity is a indirect subclass of `Context`. So then you can use this in `Toast.makeText`. But There are other things to implement to create a complete Activity. So I think you better study about basic activity creation firsts

Answer (score 1):

[Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) has two methods called `makeText()`, and both of them take a Context as first argument. `AboutMeActivity` is not a Context (I guess you want it to extend Activity, but it doesn't), so the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need activity context to display toast. I guess you want to display toast on button click and you would have defined in your layout xml for button the attribute android:onClick="showAboutMessage". Your class must extend activity. Also you need to set the content of the layout to your activity.

```
public class AboutMeActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // set the layout to the activity
 } 
public void showAboutMessage(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, "My name is Kostas!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

If you want to display toast in a non-activity class pass the activity context to the constructor of the non-activity class and use the same.